# Django crash - Segmentation fault: 11 on macOS

Tags: django, macos, internationalization, segmentation-fault

I'm installing an existing Django project on a new mac.

I'm having troubles with a Segmentation Fault: 11, only on part of the project which implements i18n translations. The segfault is intermittent (segfault occurs after 1, 2 or 3 page loading, no consistancy)

The project is running great in an other mac and on Debian.

Python3.7, Django 2.1

Here's the log from OS X High Sierra, any ideas ?

```html
Process:               python3.7 [2972]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/python3.7
Identifier:            python3.7
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [1020]
Responsible:           python3.7 [2972]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-08-07 13:50:15.936 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G2208)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     2.4.1 (15P6703)
Anonymous UUID:        4319F0E9-1882-BC12-95FB-566093869996

Sleep/Wake UUID:       DC145697-3583-415B-826B-FEEFC191ABE4

Time Awake Since Boot: 4100 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   python3.7 [2972]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff547d848a __kill + 10
1   org.python.python              0x000000010079580c os_kill + 57
2   org.python.python              0x00000001006bcf42 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 525
3   org.python.python              0x00000001006bc4af _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 44
4   org.python.python              0x000000010075310e call_function + 467
5   org.python.python              0x000000010074a305 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 2604
6   org.python.python              0x00000001006bc88e function_code_fastcall + 116
7   org.python.python              0x000000010075317a call_function + 575
8   org.python.python              0x000000010074a9a6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 4301
9   org.python.python              0x0000000100753ad1 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1837
10  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc474 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
11  org.python.python              0x000000010075317a call_function + 575
12  org.python.python              0x000000010074a305 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 2604
13  org.python.python              0x0000000100753ad1 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1837
14  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc0dd _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441
15  org.python.python              0x00000001006bd241 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
16  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc5bd PyObject_Call + 136
17  org.python.python              0x000000010074ac4e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 4981
18  org.python.python              0x0000000100753ad1 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1837
19  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc0dd _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441
20  org.python.python              0x00000001006bd241 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
21  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc5bd PyObject_Call + 136
22  org.python.python              0x000000010074ac4e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 4981
23  org.python.python              0x0000000100753ad1 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1837
24  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc0dd _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441
25  org.python.python              0x00000001006bd241 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
26  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc5bd PyObject_Call + 136
27  org.python.python              0x000000010074ac4e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 4981
28  org.python.python              0x0000000100753ad1 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1837
29  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc0dd _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441
30  org.python.python              0x00000001006bd241 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
31  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc5bd PyObject_Call + 136
32  org.python.python              0x000000010074ac4e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 4981
33  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc88e function_code_fastcall + 116
34  org.python.python              0x000000010075317a call_function + 575
35  org.python.python              0x000000010074a2ec _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 2579
36  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc88e function_code_fastcall + 116
37  org.python.python              0x000000010075317a call_function + 575
38  org.python.python              0x000000010074a2ec _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 2579
39  org.python.python              0x0000000100753ad1 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1837
40  org.python.python              0x00000001006bc474 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
41  org.python.python              0x000000010075317a call_function + 575
42  org.python.python              0x000000010074a9a6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 4301
43  org.python.python              0x0000000100753ad1 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1837
44  org.python.python              0x0000000100749851 PyEval_EvalCode + 42
45  org.python.python              0x0000000100778a5f run_mod + 54
46  org.python.python              0x0000000100777a7a PyRun_FileExFlags + 164
47  org.python.python              0x0000000100777159 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 283
48  org.python.python              0x000000010078e842 pymain_main + 5114
49  org.python.python              0x000000010078efd4 _Py_UnixMain + 104
50  libdyld.dylib                  0x00007fff54688015 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007ffeef562758  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000b9c  rsi: 0x000000000000000b  rbp: 0x00007ffeef562780  rsp: 0x00007ffeef562758
   r8: 0x000000010088e160   r9: 0x00000001007ed1d9  r10: 0xda9d3f58d1f800f9  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x0000000000000002  r13: 0x0000000100863210  r14: 0x0000000100a093b8  r15: 0x00000001030365b0
  rip: 0x00007fff547d848a  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x000000010125f4b0
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000025
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x10069b000 -        0x10069cfff +python (0) <A70EA40C-9A64-3D6D-9CB4-BD4DF9BF9613> /Users/USER/*/python
       0x1006a2000 -        0x100827fff +org.python.python (3.7.0, [c] 2001-2018 Python Software Foundation. - 3.7.0) <63F978A8-4F72-3AE4-88DE-6108758D6719> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
       0x100fc0000 -        0x100fc4ffb +math.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <37D27C6A-F45F-3951-8021-80CF2246FAFA> /Users/USER/*/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x100fca000 -        0x100fd5ff7 +_datetime.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <9974AB99-0BC1-3C0E-BD6D-7E0B1A87824A> /Users/USER/*/_datetime.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x100fdd000 -        0x100fdefff +_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <8FE97434-8B32-3165-A0E4-BC437576A992> /Users/USER/*/_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101022000 -        0x101023fff +_posixsubprocess.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <4055D61D-57DA-3005-BF42-691AAE9959C8> /Users/USER/*/_posixsubprocess.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101026000 -        0x101029fff +select.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <B3A4D7C2-67CB-3A58-B12F-0AB4DF61DB48> /Users/USER/*/select.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1010ee000 -        0x1010eefff +_opcode.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <8A7AF5BC-68EA-3B97-B606-6F725D0AB8C1> /Users/USER/*/_opcode.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10133a000 -        0x10133bfff +termios.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <267FE878-8586-340D-BCA3-B17D0F4C81D7> /Users/USER/*/termios.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10133f000 -        0x10136dff7 +_decimal.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <AA1C2914-242D-3573-BE84-E2CE58583454> /Users/USER/*/_decimal.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1013c0000 -        0x1013c3fff +_struct.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <64BF4EB7-0C70-386D-AF6E-CBC75536153E> /Users/USER/*/_struct.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10140a000 -        0x10140dff3 +binascii.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <000287D3-8FC1-37D5-8965-E256BF0A3D67> /Users/USER/*/binascii.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101411000 -        0x101416ff7 +_json.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <9DC95599-227F-3699-9A21-5AA2B53CE656> /Users/USER/*/_json.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10141a000 -        0x10141dfff +zlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <D67A3130-8DAF-35B9-AD7B-9AD1ECC26345> /Users/USER/*/zlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101422000 -        0x101425fff +_hashlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <9032193A-5958-3339-BB96-5A5B62E1BC2D> /Users/USER/*/_hashlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101429000 -        0x101468fff +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (0) <4D343D8E-B72A-38BD-9204-CC0354C0B7F8> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
       0x101487000 -        0x1015f7d67 +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (0) <4A0A66FE-A6B9-387F-B265-512C91DF46F9> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
       0x101671000 -        0x101676ffb +_blake2.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <0B3A4FEC-8874-36CE-80B1-C59DAC8A1022> /Users/USER/*/_blake2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10167a000 -        0x101689fff +_sha3.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <50C220C2-9377-3422-930A-850D9ECF4268> /Users/USER/*/_sha3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1016ce000 -        0x1016cefff +_bisect.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <73A8052C-837C-3BFE-A81B-500460ECCFBC> /Users/USER/*/_bisect.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1016d1000 -        0x1016d2fff +_random.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <755AA1A5-1D24-31E6-AB20-F6A76AE44FA3> /Users/USER/*/_random.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101715000 -        0x101716fff +_bz2.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <C66A99FB-5EAF-3333-B25F-72803EEA50A2> /Users/USER/*/_bz2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10171a000 -        0x10171dff7 +_lzma.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <FE808AC5-71E1-30E7-86C0-D64052E82B3D> /Users/USER/*/_lzma.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101722000 -        0x10173dff7 +liblzma.5.dylib (0) <423B98CF-7AF0-325D-AB6A-3F44B56B90C2> /usr/local/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
       0x101743000 -        0x101744fff +grp.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <8721F97F-B43A-3FEF-A3A1-B5C19B0BF75A> /Users/USER/*/grp.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101787000 -        0x10178fff7 +_socket.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <E39366E6-D8C9-383E-8EA5-5577887F3069> /Users/USER/*/_socket.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1018eb000 -        0x1019e8fff +unicodedata.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <FAA1B852-BDCF-3144-9204-23865E30ED4C> /Users/USER/*/unicodedata.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101a2d000 -        0x101a39fff +_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <650AB04A-4FDC-39F9-90CD-69F15F0A0893> /Users/USER/*/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101b06000 -        0x101b06fff +_uuid.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <2706F62D-0213-32D6-8582-C4FC60C3D31D> /Users/USER/*/_uuid.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101d89000 -        0x101d8afff +fcntl.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <34885A84-16EE-30AD-99F6-680C5E1CA050> /Users/USER/*/fcntl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101e8e000 -        0x101e9affb +_pickle.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <9064E805-75C1-3E05-B036-D928FDC15C82> /Users/USER/*/_pickle.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101ea4000 -        0x101ea5fff +_queue.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <8727BAED-EEEC-30EA-AB63-34184A8B4277> /Users/USER/*/_queue.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1021a8000 -        0x1021adff3 +_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <75778CEE-316E-367A-85D5-07390393A490> /Users/USER/*/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1021b9000 -        0x1024f5fff +libmysqlclient.21.dylib (0) <F48EC893-F092-39DD-AB2D-97375A048BCA> /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
       0x1026ea000 -        0x1026efff7 +array.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <F58DAFF7-EB51-31A2-8C94-F31E2A77103D> /Users/USER/*/array.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102b37000 -        0x102b84ff7 +_imaging.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <864891F8-29C6-37B2-828E-58F80FFFAEE9> /Users/USER/*/_imaging.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102bab000 -        0x102bfffff +libjpeg.9.dylib (0) <15B872D2-4E1A-3C33-A28E-78455A89C529> /Users/USER/*/libjpeg.9.dylib
       0x102c07000 -        0x102c4dff7 +libopenjp2.2.1.0.dylib (0) <60F449FD-6D0F-365B-8F45-EFE18DB51577> /Users/USER/*/libopenjp2.2.1.0.dylib
       0x102c57000 -        0x102c73ff7 +libz.1.2.11.dylib (0) <0C5030A7-879E-3231-A1E3-7F2B1B16FAC7> /Users/USER/*/libz.1.2.11.dylib
       0x102c77000 -        0x102d07ff7 +libtiff.5.dylib (0) <8311C844-E8C3-34EA-84F5-5F55C2BA1EA8> /Users/USER/*/libtiff.5.dylib
       0x102d18000 -        0x102d47ff7 +liblzma.5.dylib (0) <83760B15-BF90-32AF-AE18-90C23DB0CA8A> /Users/USER/*/liblzma.5.dylib
       0x102d8e000 -        0x102d8ffff +_scproxy.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <3B366CFC-72DC-39CC-8C6F-B75BCF9ACDC1> /Users/USER/*/_scproxy.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102da4000 -        0x102da8fff +_rl_accel.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <82ED76C9-C2BB-3FB8-95BE-92F04484AA22> /Users/USER/*/_rl_accel.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x107096000 -        0x1070e0acf  dyld (551.4) <8A72DE9C-A136-3506-AA02-4BA2B82DCAF3> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff28c6c000 -     0x7fff28c6cfff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <8632A9C5-19EA-3FD7-A44D-80765CC9C540> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff28c84000 -     0x7fff29182fc3  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - ???) <A243A7EF-0C8E-3A9A-AA38-44AFD7507F00> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff29183000 -     0x7fff292ddfe3  libBLAS.dylib (1211.50.2) <62C659EB-3E32-3B5F-83BF-79F5DF30D5CE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff292de000 -     0x7fff2930cfef  libBNNS.dylib (38.1) <7BAEFDCA-3227-3E07-80D8-59B6370B89C6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fff2930d000 -     0x7fff296ccff7  libLAPACK.dylib (1211.50.2) <40ADBA5F-8B2D-30AC-A7AD-7B17C37EE52D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff296cd000 -     0x7fff296e2ff7  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1211.50.2) <E8E0B7FD-A0B7-31E5-AF01-81781F71EBBE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff296e3000 -     0x7fff296e8ff3  libQuadrature.dylib (3) <3D6BF66A-55B2-3692-BAC7-DEB0C676ED29> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fff296e9000 -     0x7fff29769fff  libSparse.dylib (79.50.2) <0DC25CDD-F8C1-3D6E-B472-8B060708424F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
    0x7fff2976a000 -     0x7fff2977dfff  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1211.50.2) <722573CC-31CC-34B2-9032-E4F652A9CCFE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff2977e000 -     0x7fff2992bfc3  libvDSP.dylib (622.50.5) <40690941-CF89-3F90-A0AC-A4D200744A5D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff2992c000 -     0x7fff299ddfff  libvMisc.dylib (622.50.5) <BA2532DF-2D68-3DD0-9B59-D434BF702AA4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff299de000 -     0x7fff299defff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.11 - vecLib 3.11) <54FF3B43-E66C-3F36-B34B-A2B3B0A36502> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff2ab82000 -     0x7fff2ab82fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 50) <AFFBD94A-AF76-336E-B53E-57524EAE8EF3> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff2ab83000 -     0x7fff2abe9fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (377 - 445.4) <85E779EE-0219-3181-B4C4-201E4CC82AB5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff2ac82000 -     0x7fff2ada4fff  libFontParser.dylib (222.1.6) <6CEBACDD-B848-302E-B4B2-630CB16E663E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff2ada5000 -     0x7fff2adefff7  libFontRegistry.dylib (221.4) <5FDB4F1A-E15C-3ACB-A5C1-F15458C0C6DC> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff2af31000 -     0x7fff2af35ff3  com.apple.ColorSyncLegacy (4.13.0 - 1) <A5FB2694-1559-34A8-A3D3-2029F68A63CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSyncLegacy.framework/Versions/A/ColorSyncLegacy
    0x7fff2afd5000 -     0x7fff2b027ffb  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 624.1) <66FD9ED2-9630-313C-86AE-4C2FBCB3F351> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff2b028000 -     0x7fff2b036fff  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <B65FF7E6-E9B5-34D8-8CA7-63D415A8A9A6> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff2b037000 -     0x7fff2b083fff  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (13.4 - 503.2) <B90C67C1-0292-3CEC-885D-F1882CD104BE> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff2b084000 -     0x7fff2b0befff  com.apple.QD (3.12 - 404.2) <38B20AFF-9D54-3B52-A6DC-C0D71380AA5F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff2b0bf000 -     0x7fff2b0cbfff  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (7.8.1 - 7.8.1) <A08DE016-C8F2-3B0E-BD34-15959D13DBF0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff2b0cc000 -     0x7fff2b35aff7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.14 - 1.14) <E0B8B5D8-80A0-308B-ABD6-F8612102B5D8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff2b67f000 -     0x7fff2ba19ff7  com.apple.CFNetwork (902.1 - 902.1) <76EB8CB6-BF59-3BDA-BF2B-F21B161611B9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff2bf4e000 -     0x7fff2c007fff  com.apple.ColorSync (4.13.0 - 3325) <D283C285-447D-3258-A7E4-59532123B8FF> /System/Library/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff2c194000 -     0x7fff2c227ff7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.3.0 - 4.3.0) <EB35D3EC-56EA-33E6-98DC-BDC3A5FA8ACE> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff2c2b8000 -     0x7fff2c60efef  com.apple.CoreData (120 - 851) <A2B59780-FB16-36A3-8EE0-E0EF072454E0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff2c60f000 -     0x7fff2c6f2fff  com.apple.CoreDisplay (99.14 - 99.14) <A1B91ADD-828D-33A0-8A92-CC3F83DF89D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreDisplay.framework/Versions/A/CoreDisplay
    0x7fff2c6f3000 -     0x7fff2cb94fef  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1454.90) <E5D594BF-9142-3325-A62D-CF4AAF472642> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff2cb96000 -     0x7fff2d1a6fef  com.apple.CoreGraphics (2.0 - 1161.21) <375C477F-5A89-3C49-9B63-373C81A63F7E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff2d1a8000 -     0x7fff2d497fff  com.apple.CoreImage (13.0.0 - 579.5) <AAE2DFD0-9B0A-3D56-8A3E-C460BAF70394> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
    0x7fff2d86c000 -     0x7fff2d86cfff  com.apple.CoreServices (822.36 - 822.36) <C8368F17-1589-3BA5-A0E7-89CB8DF2454F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff2d86d000 -     0x7fff2d8e1ffb  com.apple.AE (735.1 - 735.1) <08EBA184-20F7-3725-AEA6-C314448161C6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff2d8e2000 -     0x7fff2dbb9fff  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1178.4 - 1178.4) <0D5E19BF-18CB-3FA4-8A5F-F6C787C5EE08> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff2dbba000 -     0x7fff2dbeefff  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 284.2) <6505B075-41C3-3C62-A4C3-85CE3F6825CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff2dbef000 -     0x7fff2dbf7ffb  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1239.50.1 - 1239.50.1) <3637CEC7-DF0E-320E-9634-44A442925C65> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff2dbf8000 -     0x7fff2ddb5fff  com.apple.LaunchServices (822.36 - 822.36) <6E68C090-B12D-3D3D-9617-E5D82C36B2D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff2ddb6000 -     0x7fff2de66ff7  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 1191.4.13) <B5C22E70-C265-3C9F-865F-B138994A418D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff2de67000 -     0x7fff2dec7fff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (822.36 - 822.36) <8684B2D7-6A1A-3ADB-A2A3-BD3ED3F4153D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff2dec8000 -     0x7fff2df36fff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <3662545A-B1CF-3079-BDCD-C83855CEFEEE> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff2df37000 -     0x7fff2df5bffb  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (71.21 - 71.21) <1B5228EF-D869-3A50-A373-7F4B0289FADD> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
    0x7fff2e1fc000 -     0x7fff2e34cfff  com.apple.CoreText (352.0 - 578.22) <6129F39D-284D-3BBF-8999-7854AB61C01C> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff2e34d000 -     0x7fff2e387fff  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 0.0) <86CCC036-51BB-3DD1-9601-D93798BCCD0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff2e68e000 -     0x7fff2e693fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <A975AD56-4CD3-3A89-8732-858CA9BD3DAA> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff2e854000 -     0x7fff2ec1afff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1454.90) <8EA924F3-ADAE-3F4B-8482-8B11C027D9A5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff2ec8b000 -     0x7fff2ecbbfff  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <41087278-74AE-3FA5-8C0E-9C78EB696299> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
    0x7fff2ef31000 -     0x7fff2efccfff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1445.71.1) <3EFECB0C-3A71-3241-B517-C5CF28B9082A> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff2efce000 -     0x7fff2efd5fff  com.apple.IOSurface (211.15 - 211.15) <9FD406F1-6BF2-35B0-8339-DF83A1A661EB> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff2f02c000 -     0x7fff2f1a6ff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1739.3) <7C579D3F-AE0B-31C9-8F80-67F2290B8DE0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff2f1a7000 -     0x7fff2f1abffb  libGIF.dylib (1739.3) <7AA44C9D-48E8-3090-B044-61FE6F0AEF38> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff2f1ac000 -     0x7fff2f293fef  libJP2.dylib (1739.3) <AEBF7260-0C10-30C0-8F0F-8B347DEE78B3> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
    0x7fff2f294000 -     0x7fff2f2b7ff7  libJPEG.dylib (1739.3) <D8C966AD-A00C-3E8B-A7ED-D7CC7ECB3224> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff2f593000 -     0x7fff2f5b9feb  libPng.dylib (1739.3) <1737F680-99D1-3F03-BFA5-5CDA30EB880A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
[...]
<08012EC0-2CD2-34BE-BF93-E7F56491299A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff54995000 -     0x7fff5499cff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (161.50.1) <6355EE2D-5456-3CA8-A227-B96E8F1E2AF8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff5499d000 -     0x7fff549a8fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (301.50.1) <0E51CCBA-91F2-34E1-BF2A-FEEFD3D321E4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff549a9000 -     0x7fff549acfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (765.70.1) <553DFCC6-9D31-3B9C-AB7C-30F6F265786D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff549ad000 -     0x7fff549aeff3  libsystem_secinit.dylib (30) <DE8D14E8-A276-3FF8-AE13-77F7040F33C1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff549af000 -     0x7fff549b6ff7  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (820.60.2) <585BDFA2-D54D-39D0-8046-44E824DABD43> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fff549b7000 -     0x7fff549cafff  libsystem_trace.dylib (829.70.1) <3A6CB706-8CA6-3616-8AFC-14AAD7FAF187> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff549cc000 -     0x7fff549d1ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <BEF3FB49-5604-3B5F-82B5-332B80023AC3> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff549d2000 -     0x7fff549ffff7  libxpc.dylib (1205.70.9) <0BC7AD67-671D-31D4-8B88-C317B8379598> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 2161
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=308.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=308.4M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=110.2M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=110.2M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                            72.4M       26 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        9 
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)            512K        3         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                          4K        2 
Stack                             16.0M        2 
VM_ALLOCATE                       20.8M       38 
__DATA                            17.0M      228 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        2 
__LINKEDIT                       194.7M       46 
__TEXT                           113.7M      225 
__UNICODE                          560K        2 
shared memory                       12K        4 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            435.9M      577 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   435.4M      577
```

Comment: Same error. I had to remove line {% load trans %}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed by switching on python3.6.6 / Django 2.1

Segfault has been identified on python3.7 on two fresh macOS installs & docker with django 2.1, this may be solved in the next django versions.

Comment: want to add that there are few ways to revert to python3.6, and most painless one is to download official python pkg and create virtual env with `pipenv --python 3.6`.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971

Steps I used to resolve:
Run - brew unlink mysql

Run - brew install mysql-connector-c

Edited the file at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config using vim

Found a line with - libs="$libs -l"

Changed it to - libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"

Then cleared my virtual environment cache

installed my dependencies (pip install -r requirements.txt)

Finally reran my django command - python manage.py migrate

This worked for me first time. FYI Python version is 3.7.2 and mysql dependencies are:
django-mysql==2.4.1

mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1

Django==2.1.7

Hope this helps as it took me hours to resolve!